# Defining global variable as a local variable in c

Tags: c

I have tried something like this :

```
int globalvar=10;

void print ()
{
    printf("%d \n",globalvar);
}

int main(){
    int globalvar=5;
    printf("%d \n",globalvar);
    print ();
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

and then the output went like this

```
5    
10
```

I have concluded that C has created a LOCAL instance of "globalvar" inside main and it's initialized with the value 10 which is printed out by printf.

I am okay with that point but I have got confused with some new points :

1. globalvar which is initialized before the main is supposed to have the scope allover the program with its same memory location in DS , what does it happen in that case where there's a variable with its same name defined locally in a function ( ex: main ),  ?
2. second question is related to the linker : How does the linker deal with these two variables of the same names so it executes in the way it executed?

PS : After downvoting the question , I want to say that I really searched the issue and I didn't find  a similar question and I thought that asking a question like this will be useful to others.
I wish I am not misunderstod

Comment: You are _shadowing_ variable names in scope. The compiler should warn you about this, with all warning levels on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have concluded that C has created a LOCAL instance of "globalvar" inside main and it's initialized with the value 10 which is printed out by printf.

No, *you* created a local variable called `globalvar` initialized to 5.  You then use it in `printf`.  `print()` has no idea at all about that variable, and uses the global one set to 10.

> what does it happen in that case where there's a variable with its same name defined locally in a function ( ex: main ), ?

Local variables take precedence.  If you want to use the global variable, you should name your local variable something different so it does not conflict.

This is all within the same file, so the linker does not deal with the interplay of these two variables at all.

Comment: I realize there is a lot more to it than this, but better to not get into the details here I think.

Comment: one more detail I want to to ask about : the globalvar is defined in both the stack(in case it's local ) and the data segment(in case it's global) ,
so is it correct to say that the priority is always given to the stack ?

Comment: @MohamedElShenawy Technically yes but I don't think that's the correct way to think about it, because scope applies to the stack as well -- you can have two variables with the same name on the stack.  The compiled program is also not going to be using "names", just addresses and storage locations -- so it doesn't matter whether the variables have the same names or different ones.

Answer (score 1):

First the printf in `main` is called. It outputs 5 - the value of the local variable defined in `main`.

Then `print` is called, and it calls printf to output the value of global variable.

Linker has nothing to worry about - it does not deal with local variables at all, they cannot be accessed by name from outside of the function they are declared in, so the name of a local variable normally is not even visible to the linker.

Answer (score 1):

Your local variable overrides your global variable inside a function. And scope of local variable will end as soon the scope of your function over.  So if you call another function which don't have a local variable in same name, you can see the global variable value.

Linker don't have any role in this feature. This feature is managed by the scope of the variable in a program.